# Adding Custom attributes to the page directive in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to add custom attributes to @Page directive and also get design time support like intellisense for the same?

I have used [Adding Custom Property to Page Directive in ASP.Net 2.0](http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/26-Adding-Custom-Property-to-Page-Directive-in-ASP-Net-2-0.aspx) as a pointer.

I would like to have a attribute which will give dev an option to select value from list. Something similar to EnableSessionState attribute. I do understand I need to define an enum for the values. But I cannot understand how to make it available during the design time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/02/421405.aspx
It might be useful

Comment: Shimmy, Thanks for posting this useful link. It indeed assign value to the property but does not give intellisense at design time. I have added more details to my question.

Comment: I am not sure you'll be able to make it appear in the intellisense; I don't know what part of the class is intellisense gather data from (i.e. reflection data, properties, directives), since it might be the 'Page' base, which is in the BCL, not the subclass of your project.

Comment: I think you are right. I will search of a solution bit more and if I don't get anything I will choose your answer :).

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Hope you find an answer, if you find something better, please post and I will vote, my point is to find solutions, not answers, if you provide the solution it will sure be useful to other including me.